# Is velocity templates good for evaluating conditions?

Tags: java, dictionary, velocity

I am thinking about externalizing some conditions instead of implementing them in java so that I can easily change them later as needed.

For example, I need to check if certain keys exist in a given map and if the values of certain keys in a map equal to something.

I was thinking about using spring's expression language, but since we are already using velocity templates, I thought maybe it is a good candidate.

Any idea? Thanks.

Comment: yes, like you mentioned, any template language implementation should have basic support for Condition checking. Check out the [Conditionals](http://velocity.apache.org/engine/devel/user-guide.html#Conditionals) section of Apache Velocity User Guide.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily use the #if/#else, #foreach and other condition functionality of velocity to do business logic as part of the velocity template rendering.

However I usually try to separate business logic from rendering in velocity for a number of reasons:

- Complexity: The Velocity template can become hard to read, especially
  if the target output itself requires complex resulting layout. If you
  add additional business logic to the mix, it quickly becomes
  impossible to read for anybody else (or for yourself after a few
  months of not looking at it constantly)
- Testability: It's harder to    test Velocity templates, there's
  better support for unit/integration testing of Java code
- Functionality: Velocity is not a full    programming language by
  design, so you will miss some things sooner    or later and a macro
  simply is not a function, e.g. variables by    default have global
  scope, ... You are bound to run into some of    these if you make
  your templates big and complex.

Comment: So it's a judgment call. If it's all about pure presentation logic, and the logic is reasonably simple and stable, using Velocity conditionals may be the best option. That's why Velocity has them in the first place.  And vice versa.